# GLSL - Problem of casting and weird bug

Tags: opengl, casting, glsl

i'm here to get help about a strange behavior of my GLSL code when i cast a float to an int and i never seen such a bug since i started GLSL

Actually i'm trying to achieve mesh skinning on CPU with GLSL

I use an ATI Radeon HD 4850 (Gainward) and i work with OpenGL 2.1 on Windows XP

so on CPU side I gather bones indices and weights, and i throw them to the shader with vertex attributes
then i multiply bones matrices with weights and use the result to compute normal and gl_Position

very usual till there

Problems come when I have to retrieve Bones from Bones indices

I work with a simple cylinder mesh skinned with 4 bones; I send the bones from the Cpu via a uniform variable and it seems that the problem doesnt come from these bones matrices, I hardcoded them in the shader and the bug remains
By the way the shape is correct when i compare with maya rendering

Moreover, the bones indices for each vertex are still the same : 0, 1, 2, 3 ; they're sent with a GL_UNSIGNED_INT type via VBO's; but in the shader the uvec4 doesn't seem to work (neither ivec4), so I have to use float vec4 and cast with int()

so here is my vertex shader code :

```
uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;

uniform mat4 bones[4];

varying vec3 normal;

attribute vec3 v_pos;
attribute vec3 v_normal;

//the 4 first bones indices of the vertex;
attribute vec4 v_boneIndices0;
//the 4 first bones weights of the vertex
attribute vec4 v_boneWeights0;

void main()
{   

/* To compare with bones sent via uniform, i hardcoded the bones matrices in this array; doesn't seem to make a difference

        mat4 mattab[4];

        mattab[0] = mat4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                         0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                         0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        mattab[1] = mat4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                         0.0f, 0.816489f, 0.57736f, 0.0f,
                         0.0f, -0.57736f, 0.816489f, 0.0f,
                         0.0f, -0.341108f, 1.07319f, 1.0f);

        mattab[2] = mat4(0.999949f, -0.00863831f, 0.00528692f, 0.0f,
                         -0.00400147f, 0.142574f, 0.989776f, 0.0f, 
                         -0.00930377f, -0.989746f, 0.142532f, 0.0f, 
                         0.00201152f, -0.00111439f, 0.865123f, 1.0f); 

        mattab[3] = mat4(0.799844f, -0.0233416f, -0.599754f, 0.0f,
                         0.448905f, 0.686556f, 0.571949f, 0.0f,
                         0.398414f, -0.726702f, 0.559616f, 0.0f, 
                         -1.23581f, -1.4976f, 2.0412f, 1.0f );

*/

        //the average matrix of weighted bones
        mat4 mat = mat4(0.0f);

        for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

               //normally, the both lines below are equivalent 
               //because v_boneIndices0 is always 0,1,3,4

               mat += v_boneWeights0[i] * bones[int(v_boneIndices0[i])];
               //mat += v_boneWeights0[i] * bones[i];  

                }

        //Here, I multiply the average matrix with v_normal and v_pos

        normal = NormalMatrix * (mat3(mat[0].xyz,mat[1].xyz,mat[2].xyz) * v_normal);

        gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix*ModelViewMatrix*(mat*vec4(v_pos, 1.0f));

}
```

the bug appears when i'm looking at the FPS rates; without skinning, i get 2000 FPS

when i use the line

`mat += v_boneWeights0[i] * bones[i];`,

i get the right shape with some artefacts, the FPS remains at 2000

but when i use the line

```
mat += v_boneWeights0[i] * bones[int(v_boneIndices0[i])];
```

(which is similar to the other line) the shape is perfect but the FPS collapses to 1500 FPS...

i thought it was the line itself that slowed the loop; however if i leave this line and remove mat from normal and gl_Position computing, the FPS rate rises to 2000

another weird behavior, if I compute

```
vec4 test = ProjectionMatrix*ModelViewMatrix*(mat*vec4(v_pos, 1.0f));
```

just after the loop, and compute Normal gl_Position without mat multiplication

```
normal = NormalMatrix * v_normal;
gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix*ModelViewMatrix* vec4(v_pos, 1.0f);
```

the FPS rate also rises to 2000

It's like the bug appears only if i combine

```
mat += v_boneWeights0[i] * bones[int(v_boneIndices0[i])];

and

normal = NormalMatrix * (mat3(mat[0].xyz,mat[1].xyz,mat[2].xyz) * v_normal);
gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix*ModelViewMatrix*(mat*vec4(v_pos, 1.0f));
```

I think it's a hardware bug, or maybe i'm doing it wrong, I don't know
But I'm sure the problem is related to the cast int()
And by the way, why uvec4 and ivec4 don't work ?

has anyone encountered this kind of behaviour with Nvidia ? I found nothing on Google

I hope you'll be able to help me

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Your error is that you look at the *frames per second* for performance instead of *the time per frame (timedelta)*. The difference between 2000 fps and 1500 fps is abysmall. 2000 fps means 0.5 ms per frame. 1500 fps means 0.6 ms per frame. The correlation between fps and time per frame is *not* linear. Effective fps is 1/timedelta. The more fps you have, the more sensitive the fps becomes because the time window is so small. Say if you had 10,000 fps, and it fluctuated between 10,000 fps and 5,000 fps. That would give you a time window between 0.1 ms and 0.2 ms. At that point, any operation could affect the timedelta.

Comment: interesting, i know FPS is not very accurate, but it's actually not the topic
how do you explain the difference for two lines of code that do exactly the same thing (if you read the code above ?)
how about the cast and its validity ?

Comment: Oh, and those aren't casts. They are constructors.

Comment: ok solved, i just declared the bone indices as float on the CPU side

no slowdown now, but ivec4 and uvec4 still don't work :(

Answer (score 0):

ivec4 and uvec4 aren't part of GLSL in OpenGL 2.1, it's an extension (GL_EXT_gpu_shader4), so you need to enable that extension using:

```
#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 : enable
```

At the beginning of your shader, and then you'll be able to use real integers in shaders. Notice that this extension is supported only in DX 10 and newer cards (which your card does).

The extension is part of Core OpenGL 3.0.

Comment: no, only uvec4. Sure at 99.99%, see http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_EXT_gpu_shader4.txt